# Is it possible to pass multiple arguments to onChange action in Ember Power Select?

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently using the excellent [ember-power-select](https://ember-power-select.com) add on as part of an [ember-bootstrap form](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.Form.html).

I have multiple drop down items on the form and I am trying to unify how they are handled into a single function that can be used as the `onChange` action in the power-select invocations:

```
{{#form.element 
    controlType="power-select" 
    label="Destination" 
    value=destinationSelection
    options=destinationOptions
    as |el|}}
    {{#el.control   
        onChange=(action "setDropDown")
        searchField="name"  
        as |item|}}
        {{item.name}}
    {{/el.control}}
{{/form.element}}
```

My handler function will simply set some values based on the selection of the drop down:

```
actions: {
     setDropDown(selected, string) {
      handleDropDown(selected, dropdown, this)
    }
}

function handleDropDown(selected, dropdown, controller) {
  let selection = `${dropdown}Selection`
  let modelid = `model.${dropdown}_id`

  set(controller, selection, selected)
  set(controller, modelid, selected.id)

}
```

In order for this to work I really need to be able to pass a string to the `setDropDown` action from the `onChange` part of the component call, otherwise I have no way of telling the handler function which particular fields it should be setting without creating an action per dropdown.

However when I try passing in multiple arguments like

```
onChange=(action "setDropDown" "destination")
```

or

```
onChange=(action "setDropDown" selected "destination")
```

I lose the basic functionality of the `onChange` action taking the selected item as it's first argument.

I looked through the documentation and couldn't find any examples where the library author is passing multiple arguments into the `onChange` action and wondered if it was possible without breaking the functionality of the library.

Comment: Any reason you are not using `model` / `property` approach of Ember Bootstraps `bs-form` component? In that case you wouldn't need an `onChange` action at all.

Comment: @jelhan great and valid question, the simple answer is that I couldn't really see what the codeblock would look like when using `ember-power-select` inside the `{{#form.element}}` component. All I am really trying to get out of these menus is for my `model.propertyName_id` to be the `id` property of the object selected in the drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a specialized higher order helper function to create an action for `ember-power-select` that will ultimately invoke your action with extra arguments. Consider this helper `handle-dropdown`

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export function invokeFunction([prop, action]) {
    return function(){
        action(prop, ...arguments);
    }
}

export default helper(invokeFunction);
```

So what we are doing here is creating the function that will be invoked by `ember-power-select`. In this function, we are invoking the original action with `prop` first, followed by every argument that `ember-power-select` invoked our `onchange` function with.

In your template, invoke this helper when passing your action to `power-select`

```
{{#power-select 
   onchange=(handle-dropdown 'foo' (action 'dropdownChanged')) 
   as |dropdown|}}
```

And then your action would be

```
actions: {
  dropdownChanged(keyToSet, selectedValue){
    this.set(keyToSet, selectedValue);
  }
}
```

This would ultimately call `dropdownChanged('foo', /* the selected value */)`

Comment: Very useful answer, thank you. For others reference I've just used it successfully in Ember 3.8 with Ember Power Select 2.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

[Ember Bootstrap's Power Select integration](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap-power-select) gives you a nice API for use cases like this one. Let me give you an example.

Lets take a country selector as an example. We have a list of countries represented by a list of objects holding their two-letters country code as defined by ISO 3166-1 as `id` property and their name as `name`. The selected country should be represented on the model which is a POJO by there country code.

```js
export default Component.extend({
  // country code of country selected or null
  selectedCountry: null,

  // Using a computed property here to ensure that the array
  // isn't shared among different instances of the compontent.
  // This isn't needed anymore if using native classes and
  // class fields.
  countries: computed(() => {
    return [
      { id: 'us', name: 'United States of America' },
      { id: 'ca', name: 'Canada' },
    ];
  }),

  // Using a computed property with getter and setter to map
  // country code to an object in countries array.
  selectedCountryObject: computed('selectedCountry', {
    get() {
      return this.countries.find((_) => _.id === this.selectedCountry);
    },
    set(key, value) {
      this.set('selectedCountry', value.id);
      return value;
    }
  }),
});
```

Now we could use Ember Bootstrap Power Select as expected:

```
{{#bs-form model=this as |form|}}  
  {{form.element controlType="power-select" property="selectedCountryObject" label="Country" options=this.countries}}
{{/bs-form}}
```

Disclaimer: Haven't tested that code myself, so there might be typos but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for expanding into an example. I can see now how the `power-select` integration API works although for my specific use case I think this kind of implementation would cause problems in other areas of the application (of course you weren't to know this as I didn't include it in the OP). It's definitely helped me understand the add on better though so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second argument in the template like this.
The selected option will automagically be sent to the function.

```
  <PowerSelect
    @selected={{this.selectedPrice}}
    @options={{this.priceRange}}
    @onChange={{fn this.choosePrice "minPrice"}}
    class="w-64"
    as |price|
  >
    {{price.title}}
  </PowerSelect>
```

Then create your function to handle the click, you need to define the 2 arguments. The argument you defined in the template will always appear first so that should be your first argument.

```
  @action
  choosePrice(type, price) {
    // type will be 'minPrice'
    // price will be the option you selected
  }
```