# ember-bootstrap - rendering "radio" inputs

Tags: ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, ember-bootstrap

Using the Ember addon ember-bootstrap I can make a set of radio buttons like this :

```
{{form.element controlType="radio" label="Fruit Type" property="radio" options=radioOptions optionLabelPath="label"}}
```

with a Controller that looks like this :

```
export default Controller.extend({

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.radioOptions = [
      {
        label: 'Citrus',
        value: 'C',
        inline: true
      },
      {
        label: 'Non-Citrus',
        value: 'N',
        inline: true
      }
    ];
  }

});
```

The relevant doco is here https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/forms .

However what I can't do is provide a custom value to each radio button so that I end up with rendered HTML like this :

```
  <label>Citrus</label>  
  <input type="radio" value="C">
  <label>Non-Citrus</label>  
  <input type="radio" value="N">
```

I have looked at "Custom Controls" on https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/forms but I can't see how that applies to this case.

---

**EDIT**: Just to be clearer about why I want to do this I want to display the readable label (eg "Citrus") but have the non-readable value ("C") available to send back to the server (because the server thinks in terms of "C" or "N".

It's not essential I could send "Citrus" back and map it around on the server but I just thought this would be very straightforward.

Looking at the part of the doco starting with "You can also just customize the existing control component:" on https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/forms it does seem like you should be able to do the sort of thing I'm after but the example shown doesn't address the use of a value attribute and I can't figure out how to .

Comment: Could you please describe your use case? Why do you need to set that `value` attribute on `input` element in the first case? Is this only about rendering correct HTML or are you trying to actual use that value for updating `property` if the radio is selected?

Comment: @Jelhan : Thanks for your comment. I'm just going to edit the question to address your question.

Comment: Did you considered using a computed property to map selected `radioOption` to `value` of your model? Similar to what I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253685/is-it-possible-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-onchange-action-in-ember-power-sele/56255640#56255640)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have the HTML rendered like that. if you want to access the checked radio, simply it is the property name dot value like `radio.value`.

Here how to get it in the on submit action:

```
  actions: {
    onSubmit() {
      alert(this.radio.value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do appreciate it but I don't think I made myself clear so I'm about to edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: That will do the job `radio.value` will have the value that you need `C` or `N`.. etc

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue but I finally solved it. You have to use `form.element` in block mode. Why is it also necessary to also write an action to update the value? I have no idea!

In my implementation, I'm using Ember changesets and my property is called `usageType`. I hope it's clear enough to adapt for your needs.

I'm also using [Ember Truth Helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers), which is what the `{{eq opt.value el.value}}` part is. It sets `checked` to true if the input value is `eq`ual to the current-selected value.

```
# my-component.js

actions: {
  selectUsageType(option) {
      return this.set('changeset.usageType', option);
    }
}
```

```
# usage-type-options.js (imported in component JS)

[{
  label: 'First label',
  value: 'A'
},
{
  label: 'Second label',
  value: 'B'
}]

# Etc.
```

```
# my-component.hbs

# I'm not using angle-bracket invovation here, oops

{{#form.element
  property="usageType"
  label="My label" as |el|
}}
  {{#each usageTypeOptions as |opt|}}
    <div class="form-check">
      <input
        type="radio"
        class="form-check-input"
        id="{{el.id}}-{{opt.value}}"
        checked={{eq opt.value el.value}}
        onchange={{action "selectUsageType" opt.value}}
      >
      <label for="{{el.id}}-{{opt.value}}" class="form-check-label">
        {{opt.label}}
      </label>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/form.element}}
```